# is there exists a continuous function f : S → S such that f(x) ≠ x for all x ∈ S?

Tags: real-analysis

Let S ⊆ R. Consider the statement:
“There exists a continuous function f : S → S such that

f(x) ≠ x for all x ∈ S.

This statement is false if S equals

(A) [2, 3]

(B) (2, 3]

(C) [−3, −2] ∪ [2, 3]

(D) (−∞, ∞)..

im completely struck ,,,,,, pliz help me  ... any hint  or any solution...i will appreciate

Comment: For a basic approach, consider using the intermediate value theorem. For a more advanced approach, consider which spaces have the *fixed point property* and remember that homeomorphisms preserve this property.

Comment: What about $S=\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri ,,but  fixed  point say c is a fixed point of the function f(x) if f(c) = c,,,im confused

Comment: What about choice C? A function that swaps the two intervals

Comment: @ziggurism,,,not getting question is about interval not set

Comment: @lomberlego Yes that's what a fixed point is. You want to find functions which have no fixed points, but some spaces $S$ have the fixed point property, that is, any continuous function $f:S\longrightarrow S$ has a fixed point.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri,,,none  of the option is vaild,,,,because by intermediate thorem  A) [2, 3]

 (B) (2, 3] 

(C) [−3, −2] ∪ [2, 3] 

(D) (−∞, ∞).....all has fixed point

Comment: A set cannot have a fixed point. We can speak of a set having the fixed point property, or of a particular function having a fixed point.

Comment: For choice C, a function which swaps the two intervals cannot have a fixed point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A) is false, i.e. $[2,3]$ has the Fixed Point Property. Consider a continuous function

$$f:[2,3]\to[2,3]$$

and define

$$g:[2,3]\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$g(x)=f(x)-x$$

It follows that $g(2)\geq 0$ and $g(3)\leq 0$. By the intermediate value theorem there is $x_0\in[2,3]$ such that $g(x_0)=0$. Thus $f(x_0)-x_0=0$ and so $f(x_0)=x_0$.

(B) is true, $(2,3]$ doesn't have the Fixed Point Property. For that take $f:(2,3]\to(2,3]$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x+1$.

(C) is true, $[-3,-2]\cup [2,3]$ doesn't have the Fixed Point Property. For that take

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
2&\mbox{if }x\in[-3,-2] \\
-2&\mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

(D) is true, $(-\infty, \infty)$ doesn't have the Fixed Point Property: $f(x)=x+1$.

Comment: thanks a lots  ton times  @freakish